# Make a dump of a session on fiddler without modification of Fiddler Rules

Tags: powershell, fiddler

I want to do this things :

- select a session
- make a dump of this session (the issue is here)

Plus, I want to do that without modification of Fiddler Rules. I have done this with a modification of Fiddler Rules but the program will be used on several machines and it can be difficult to change Fiddler Rules in every machines.

I don't know if it is possible.

The code to do that with the modification of the fiddler Rules is :

PowerShell :

```
$filePath = "...\nameFile.txt" # file which contain the names of fiddler ZIP files
$file = Get-Content $filePath # content of nameFile
foreach ($line in $file) {
    start $line # open the file
    Write-Host "File : $line open"
    Start-Sleep -s 1    
}

& "...\Fiddler\ExecAction.exe" "failuresselection" # select all failures and make another file (see Fiddler Rules)
```

Fiddler Rules :

```
static function OnExecAction(sParams: String[]): Boolean {
   [...]
   // Select all failures and put them in a new ZIP file
   case "failuresselection":
      var path = "...\\Newlogs";                        
      UI.actSelectSessionsWithResponseCode(449);
      if (UI.GetFirstSelectedSession() != null){
       UI.actSaveSessionsToZip(path+"\\Logs" + 449 + ".saz");   
      }
      // Confirmation 
      FiddlerObject.StatusText = "Dumped all failures sessions to " + path; 
      UI.actExit();
      return true;
      [...]
}
```

I try this but it doesn't worked :

```
& "...\Fiddler\ExecAction.exe" "FiddlerApplication.UI.actSelectAll();"
```

It's to select all line but I think that ExecAction.exe replace QuickExec.

In summary, I am searching a way to do the same thing without modification of Fiddler Rules.